# About support JavaScript Modules in browsers (native, without babel or require.js)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I do not where I can not find information about the future of the native support for JavaScript Modules in browsers (preferably Google Chrome)

According to this document http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-modules, the modules are included in the ECMAScript 2015 (or ES6) but support in browsers for which it is still no. Also, I did not find anything about the modules in [ECMAScript 6 Compability Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

What is known about support JavaScript Modules (import and export) in browsers?

Comment: [MDN: import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [Previewing ES6 Modules and more from ES2015, ES2016 and beyond](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/17/es6-modules-and-beyond/)

Comment: The status of the major browsers can be found in the [github repository of the loader spec](https://github.com/whatwg/loader).

Answer (score 2):

ES6 Modules are part of the specification, well that's true, at least as far as I know. The ES6 standard however does not define how to load them and that's the problem.

I've found a nice summary on how you may get modules working in modern browsers here:
https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-what-are-modules