# Replacing JavaScript Modules for Browser Support

Tags: javascript, import, module

I've been working on a personal project to make a random character generator for an rpg, and am having difficulties getting it to work in browser. I've identified the issue as my use of modules and imports to handle JavaScripts, which is causing the CORS policy to block it.

I want to know if there's a method to replace these modules and imports; I believe I could simply move every function into a single .js file, but that seems like it would make the file far less manageable. For reference, my program is being hosted [here](http://sagaeditioncharactergenerator.great-site.net/CharGen%20Project/), and these are the code lines in question:

Head of html file:

```
<script src="javascripts/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

multiple lines of imports in index.js file:

```
import {references} from './references.js';
```

I attempted to remove the typing of the index.js file as a module, but that caused the import statements to fail, and have not found relevant answers in searches of other module questions on stack overflow. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524122/about-support-javascript-modules-in-browsers-native-without-babel-or-require-j) was the closest I could find with some reading on the subject, but it didn't actually address my issue.

Comment: The CORS errors are a misnomer to the actual problem being that the `import`s for `speciesGen.js'` and `speed.js` lead to 404s. This seems to suggest that the `import` paths for these scripts are incorrect.